# Can I prevent Jungle Disk's "Compressing Backup Database" process from spiking my CPU?

Tags: backup, amazon-s3, jungledisk

Every time my scheduled backup runs, it spikes my CPU usage up to 100%, literally freezing everything else I'm doing.
It is only during the 'Compressing Backup Database' part of the backup process that the CPU usage is like this.

**Is there some way of throttling the CPU that JungleDisk will use for its compression process?**

The current process I have with my backups are that they run frequently (every 15 min), that way it need only upload a megabyte or so each time. I don't want to lower the frequency, as the machine is only on while I'm working on it, and even then I don't have internet access 50% of the time. I'm running this off a 32 bit Windows XP Virtualbox machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed their support and got this answer:

> Unfortunately, this type of usage is likely due to the heavy usage of
>   compression within our code base. We have a bug ticket open to address
>   this type of usage in the next milestone release of Jungle Disk. At
>   this time, we simply don't have a solution for the high CPU usage.
>
> As a work around, you can switch your backup to a Legacy Backup. This
>   would eliminate the compression that Jungle Disk is performing.
>   However, note that a Legacy Backup does not perform any compression or
>   de-duplication. In addition, you would need to re-upload your data.
>
> Simply go to your Jungle Disk client configuration and define a Legacy
>   Backup.

Seems to have been **solved with a later version**.